# Finding folders that contain changed files since date

Tags: macos, mac, unix, applescript

So, I have a directory with lots of sub-directories
Something like...

```
main
main/folder1
main/folder2
main/folder2/otherfolder1
main/folder2/otherfolder2
```

etc...

Is there an easy way for me to determine which folders have files in them that have been changed since a particular date?

I'd want to know that

```
folder1
otherfolder2
```

Are the only two folders that have changed files since 7/15/09.

Anything simple will work for me...applescript, terminal command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type d -newermt '7/15/09'
```

From the find man page:

-newerXY file

True if the current file has a more recent last access time
(X=a), inode creation time (X=B), change time (X=c), or modification time (X=m) than the last access time (Y=a), inode creation
time (Y=B), change time (Y=c), or modification time (Y=m) of
file.  In addition, if Y=t, then file is instead interpreted as a
direct date specification of the form understood by cvs(1).  Note
that -newermm is equivalent to -newer.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/01/19/find-files-that-are-modified-today-or-since-certain-time-ago-in-unix/) article shows how this can be done using find in terminal. For more information on find open a terminal and use

```
man find
```

Comment: You may as well say "An answer does exist, but I won't tell you what it is, go find out for yourself"

Comment: @frumbert You are aware you are responding to a more than 10 year old answer that has already has a higher voted answer and was made before all the latest posting rules. SuperUser at work as it is meant to be. :)